# Send Mail in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I need to send email using Node Js. I have used the following code,

```
    var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
//var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport")
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
   service: "Gmail",
   auth: {
       user: "example@gmail.com",
       pass: "xxxxxxxx"
   }
});
smtpTransport.sendMail({
           from: "example@gmail.com", // sender address
           to: "example@gmail.com", // comma separated list of receivers
           subject: "Test Mail", // Subject line
           text: "Hi, Test Mail"// plaintext body
        }, function(error, data){

           if(error){
               console.log(error);
           }else{
               console.log("Mail Sent");
           }
        });
```

When I run this code, I get error,

```
   { AuthError: Invalid login - 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsO
534-5.7.14 nSiseM4eUKjA64AZjuUfbMQisituUebEXGcWjgh1aePgnHNUs2gNlmIrmDHMY-VHZpi_-_ShO
534-5.7.14 5piXf2MTbZWxaEbFpal3ZqHZlUIvWc8vdCZBhjuhBlzVzALTv0Swes374SR7bwoalfGGIgHI
534-5.7.14 n7mxubIXPM_BM0ehxuh2tqDLL9n3wilsOpyShjhzLZ3hZg_baUdUT2lKp2MBzXRtblrD6nDw
534-5.7.14 hL-u0QueUcDAVi0XsZqjLmmhGozaM> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y205sm10903842pfb.13 - gsmtp
    at SMTPClient._actionAUTHComplete (/var/www/html/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:925:23)
    at SMTPClient._onData (/var/www/html/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:354:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:542:20)
  name: 'AuthError',
  data: '534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsO\r\n534-5.7.14 nSiseM4eUKjA64AZjuUfbMQisituUebEXGcW1aePgnHNUs2ghjhNlmIrmDHMY-VHZpi_-_ShO\r\n534-5.7.14 5piXf2MTbZWxaEbFpal3ZqHZlUIvWc8vdCZBuhBlzVzALTvhjh0Swes374SR7bwoalfGGIgHI\r\n534-5.7.14 n7mxubIXPM_BM0ehxuh2tqDLL9n3wilsOpyShzLZ3hZg_bahjUdUT2lKp2MBzXRtblrD6nDw\r\n534-5.7.14 hL-u0QueUcDhjAVi0XsZqjLmmhGozaM> Please log in via your web browser and\r\n534-5.7.14 then try again.\r\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\r\n534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y205sm10903842pfb.13 - gsmtp',
  stage: 'auth' }
```

I have allowed access to my gmail account using the following link

```
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
```

But still I am getting this error.Please help.

Answer (score 3):

1. For Gmail you may need to configure **"Allow Less Secure Apps"** in your Gmail account. [Click Here.](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
2. If you are using 2FA in that case you would have to create an **Application specific password.**
3. You also may need to unlock your account with **"Allow access to your Google account"** to use SMTP.

I can upload a working example on github if you wish. Authentication is the error here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have configured first and third one as you said. I dont know what is the second one you are saying here 2FA?. Please upload a working example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication. Two-Step-Verification in case of Gmail.

Comment: Still the issue persists. Can you post me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue solved..Login to your Google account using a browser, then visit the link below to unlock it: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: single-line solution should be in comment.